# different field then expected being put out in html

Tags: python, html, django

When I try to put out comment in my html, author's email instead of comment is being put out somehow: 
    asdas(Oct. 22, 2011, 2:38 p.m.)
    marijus.merkevicius@gmail.com

Here's my models :

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    comment = models.TextField()
    entry = models.ForeignKey(Entry)
```

Here's my view:

```
def detail(request, blog_slug):
    entry = get_object_or_404(Entry, slug = blog_slug)

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            comment = Comment(name = cd["name"], email = cd["email"],
                              comment = cd["email"],
                              entry = entry)
            comment.save()

            return redirect("blog.views.detail", blog_slug = blog_slug)
    else:
        form = CommentForm()

    comments = Comment.objects.filter(entry = entry)

    return render_to_response("detail.html", {"entry" : entry,
                                              "comments" : comments,
                                              "form" : form},
                              context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

And here's my template:

```
{% for comment in comments %}
    <p>{{ comment.name }}(<i>{{ comment.pub_date }}</i>)<br/>{{ comment.comment }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you store the email address in the comment field:

```
comment = cd["email"],
```